# Keeping postgresql files from being deleted every reboot?

Tags: kali-linux, postgresql

Every time i restart my Kali machine, my postgresql service cannot start properly. For a while i did not know what it was, but i soon found out that this directory and file keeps being deleted.

```
/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat
```

After running,

```
mkdir /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp
touch global.stat
```

I can now successfully start the service.

However, this is the output from my postgresql.log.

```
2018-01-29 16:46:03.278 UTC [1890] WARNING:  corrupted statistics file 
"/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2018-01-29 16:46:03.289 UTC [1890] WARNING:  corrupted statistics file 
"/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2018-01-29 16:46:03.299 UTC [1890] WARNING:  corrupted statistics file 
"/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2018-01-29 16:46:03.310 UTC [1890] WARNING:  corrupted statistics file 
"/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2018-01-29 16:46:03.322 UTC [1890] WARNING:  corrupted statistics file 
"/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2018-01-29 16:46:03.333 UTC [1890] WARNING:  corrupted statistics file 
"/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2018-01-29 16:46:03.343 UTC [1890] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of 
current ones because stats collector is not responding
2018-01-29 16:46:03.343 UTC [1890] WARNING:  corrupted statistics file 
"/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2018-01-29 16:46:35.896 UTC [1885] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2018-01-29 16:46:38.988 UTC [1885] LOG:  worker process: logical replication 
launcher (PID 1892) exited with exit code 1
2018-01-29 16:46:38.990 UTC [1887] LOG:  shutting down
2018-01-29 16:46:39.125 UTC [1885] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

This is what is inside of postgresql.conf

```
# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'      # use data in another 
directory
                # (change requires restart)
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf'    # host-based 
authentication file
                # (change requires restart)
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_ident.conf'    # ident 
configuration file
                # (change requires restart)
```

This is Postgres version 10.

Linux Kali 4.14.0-kali3-686-pae (2018-01-25) i686 GNU/Linux running on VMware

Comment: Have you checked the logs?.

Comment: `/run` and `/var/run` are often `tmpfs`, so nothing should be depending on having files or directories there survive past a reboot

Comment: Kali is not a general purpose OS.  It is a crippled, deliberately broken distribution allegedly for security professionals (IMO it seems very unlikely that any would actually WANT to use kali so it seems far more likely to be a honeypot for wanna-be script-kiddies).  Don't use kali if you're not a) a masochist, **and** b) an expert security professional doing real "penetration testing" (i.e. that isn't a euphemism for clumsily and incompetently trying to hack someone else's network without authorisation).  Use a distro that isn't broken instead.

Comment: i am using postgresql-10

Comment: I had already tried purging postgre*, and reinstalling, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i came up with.

```
crontab -e
```

Followed by

```
@reboot mkdir /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp
@reboot touch /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat
```

When i reboot my pc everything is just fine and ready to go!

Comment: There was a solution to a similar problem posted on [github](https://github.com/torhve/pix/issues/2) that may worth a try

Answer (score 0):

`/var/run` is a symbolic link to `/run`. You can see this by running `ls -l`.

You can also set the Postgresql service to depend on another directory where you can store the files it depends on.

Comment: Here's a pointer towards a much better answer: What does the PostgreSQL doco _explicitly state_ about the placement of the statistics collector's temporary files and what is supposed to happen at shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have downloaded 2018-01-25, which is a [potentially unstable](http://cdimage.kali.org/kali-weekly/) version of Kali used for testing the distribution itself.

Throw that version away and get a copy from the official released downloads page at https://www.kali.org/downloads/.

Comment: That is the location of the current download. It is a vmware image.

Comment: Everything was fine until an improper shutdown.

Comment: So why didn't you TELL US is was a VMware image?